# Does the Lagrangian have to have units of energy?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conventions, dimensional-analysis, action

I've read that the standard formulation of the lagrangian is $L = T-V$ which has energy units (Joules).

But when I read a bit about electromagnetism and relativity I've seen that the lagrangian is built upon constraints of symmetries and such.

How does lagrangians like that of Einstein-Hilbert action or electromagnetism relate to $T-V$? How could the product of the square root of the determinant of the metric tensor and the Ricci scalar give units of the lagrangian density? Is there no restrictions on units? Please excuse any misinformation and point any out if you could.

Comment: A number of comments removed. To post a brief answer to the question, please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrangian of a classical, nonrelativistic system indeed has units of energy, because it is given by
$$L = T-V.$$
From the Lagrangian, you define the action of the system as
$$S = \int dt\: L$$
I hope, you are familiar with natural units. Otherwise I highly recommend you read up on them, because it makes these considerations much easier. I will use them in this discussion.

In natural units, the unit of time (and space) is 1/Energy, so the action is dimensionless.
Once you get into relativity, the above definition of the Lagrangian and the action doesn't make sense anymore. This is because time and space are not on equal footing. You only integrate over the time coordinate, and the potential only depends on the space-coordinate. The whole concept of a potential doesn't make sense in a relativistic context. Thus, this expression is not going to be Lorentz invariant.

To define the action in a Lorentz-invariant way, we have to integrate over all space-time coordinates. So in 4-D, we write

$$S = \int d^4x \: \mathcal{L}$$

The action is still dimensionless, so the natural unit of $\mathcal{L}$ is $$[\mathcal{L}] = [\frac{1}{x^4}] = [E^4]$$ The unit of $\mathcal{L}$ is equal to the unit of L divided by a volume. For that reason $\mathcal{L}$ is called Lagrangian density.

The Einstein Hilbert action is given by
$$S = \frac{c^4}{16\pi G} \int \sqrt{-g}\: R\: d^4x$$
In natural units, $c$ is dimensionless, and the gravitational constant has units of area or inverse energy squared:
$$[G] = [\frac{1}{E^2}]$$
We can thus write
$$\mathcal{L} \sim \frac{1}{G}\sqrt{-g} \:R $$
up to a numerical, unitless factor.

We know that the metric has to be dimensionless. This follows from the definition of the line element:
$$ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$$
Both $ds$ and $dx^\mu$ have units of length (or inverse energy), so if you compare both sides, you find that $g$ cannot carry any extra units.

But what about the Ricci scalar $R$? The Ricci scalar contains second derivatives of the metric. Each derivative has units of inverse length or energy. Thus,
$$[R] = [E^2]$$
and therefore
$$[\mathcal{L}] = [\frac{R}{G}] = [E^4]$$
Thus, the action is dimensionless and everything is consistent.

Comment: This is a very interesting topic, I never knew units were this manipulatable. I'll definitely read about it more. Thanks!

Comment: @user1127202 You could also do this whole analysis in SI or CGS units, but it's going to be very tedious. Plus, if you want to learn more about theoretical physics, you should definitely get familiar with natural units, because they are used in almost every textbook.

Answer (score 1):

First off: we have that there is no single algorithm to arrive at the Lagrangian of a particular field of physics. Not only is the Lagrangian for each distinct field of physics a bespoke Lagrangian, the way to arrive at that Lagrangian is bespoke too.

Still, there is a common element: arriving at the Lagrangian involves doing the *inverse* of the operation that the Euler-Lagrange equation performs.

The operation that the Euler-Lagrange equation performs is  differentiation with respect to the position coordinate.

For classical mechanics:
with:
$s$ => position
$v$ => velocity
$a$ => acceleration
$t$ => time
$L$ => $(E_k - E_p)$

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial s} - \  \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial v} \right) = 0  \tag{1} $$

Since the potential energy is a function of $s$ only, and the kinetic energy is a function of $v$ only: specifying partial differentiation is superfluous, and the expression simplifies to:

$$ \frac{d(-E_p)}{ds} - \ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{dE_k}{dv} \right) = 0  \tag{2} $$

(2) can equivalently be stated as follows:

$$ \frac{d(-E_p)}{ds} - \frac{d(E_k)}{ds}  = 0  \tag{3} $$

The inverse of the operation specified by (3) is *integration* with respect to the position coordinate.

We take $F=ma$, and we obtain the integral with respect to the position coordinate for both sides.

To prepare: we take the case of an arbitrary acceleration $a$, and we integrate that from starting position $s_0$ to position $s$

The evaluation of the integral uses (4) and (5) for change of differential. Each time the limits change accordingly.

$ ds = v \ dt \quad (4)$
$ a \ dt = dv \quad (5) $
$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \int_{t_0}^t a \ v \ dt = \int_{t_0}^t v \ a \ dt = \int_{v_0}^v v \ dv = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2 \tag{6} $$

With the intermediate steps removed:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2 \tag{7} $$

This is a very general result: there is no restriction on the acceleration profile.

(7) is not a physical property; (7) is a mathematial property. The underlying property is that zero derivative, first derivative and second derivative are an interconnected trio.

Next: perform integration of both sides of $F=ma$

$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \int_{s_0}^s ma \ ds \tag{8} $$

Use (7) for the integration of the acceleration:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2 \tag{9} $$

(9) is the Work-Energy theorem, of course.

(9) gives the quantities that make up the Lagrangian of classical mechanics.

The key point:
The Euler-Lagrange equation is an operator that performs differentiation with respect to the position coordinate. To construct the Lagrangian: perform the inverse operation of that: integration with respect to the position coordinate.

If the integration is performed correctly the dimensions will match.

Verification:

(3) specifies taking the derivative of the kinetic energy with respect to the position coordinate. Here is how that works out:

$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{ds} = \tfrac{1}{2}m\left( 2v\frac{dv}{ds} \right) = m\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{dv}{ds} = m\frac{dv}{dt} = ma \tag{10} $$

Comparison: the operation specified by the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dv} \right) = \frac{d}{dt} (mv) = ma \tag{11} $$

(10) and (11) evaluate to the same quantity, demonstrating that the starting points are mathematically the same.